# AND statement is not getting executed in Python algotrading

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, loops, if-statement

This is a paper trading algo code. For some reason if no. 2 and if no. 4 are not getting executed. I have used the same code for backtesting and it worked perfectly. But while when deployed live I'm getting few problems in the flow of program.Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
position = 'Close'
while True:
    df =pd.DataFrame(kite.historical_data(instrument_id, from_date='2020-12-01', to_date='2020-12-04', interval='minute'))
    i = (len(df.index)-1)
    LTP = kite.ltp(symbol)[symbol]['last_price']

    if (EMACrossover_bull(df, i) or consolidation_bull(df, i)) and (position == 'Close'): #if no. 1
        position = 'Open1'
        entry = LTP
        entry_time = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        target = entry*(1+tar)
        stop_loss = entry*(1-stl)
        print('{} Long position initiated at {}. Target: {} Stop Loss:{}'.format(entry_time, entry, target, stop_loss))

    if (position == 'Open1') and (LTP > target or LTP < stop_loss):  #if no. 2
        position = 'Close'
        exitt = LTP
        exit_time = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        change = exitt-entry
        print('{} Long position closed at {}. G/L: {} '.format(exit_time, exitt, change))

    if (EMACrossover_bear(df, i) or consolidation_bear(df, i)) and (position == 'Close'):  #if no. 3
        position = 'Open2'
        entry = LTP
        entry_time = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        target = entry*(1-tar)
        stop_loss = entry*(1+stl)
        print('{} Short position initiated at {}. Target: {} Stop Loss:{}'.format(entry_time, entry, target, stop_loss))

    if (position == 'Open2') and (LTP < target or LTP > stop_loss):  #if no. 4
        position = 'Close'
        exitt = LTP
        exit_time = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        change = entry-exitt
        print('{} Short position closed at {}. G/L: {} '.format(exit_time, exitt, change))
```

This is the output I'm getting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8D2fk.jpg)

Comment: Besides the point that we have no way of running your code, since we have no access to the data frames, have you tried printing out the values in your if statement just before it? Because it seems like LTP is in the middle of `target` and `stop_loss`, so it should skip that statement.

Comment: Hey thank you for taking time to look at the code. The thing is that it is not about the dataframe, LTP, target or stop_loss. Its about the variable 'position'. If you look at how the values of 'position are updated you will observe that no two' ifs' should run consecutively since value of 'position' is updated in each if block. If you see the output if block 3 has executed consecutively multiple times. That is what baffles me

Answer (score 0):

With LTP = 96, target = 89, stoploss = 193 and position = Open2 then

```
if (position == 'Open2') and (LTP < target or LTP > stop_loss):  #if no. 4
         true            and (   false     or    false )
         true            and              false
                        false
```

will not be true.

Is this what you expect?